# Why should (if at all) one consider EOS instead of Ethereum for smart contracts and dapps?

Tags: blockchain

Now that EOS testnet has been live for almost a month, what are your views on the capabilities of EOS(advertised vs actual). If one has to build a distributed application today then should EOS be considered a serious candidate?

Comment: Consider re-asking at [EOS.io site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio/visit).